# RegEx with a certain string and any amount of chars after that

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have a regex that will check if a certain string exists in another string and has any amount of chars after that. I wrote this expression:

```
(somesite.com\/user\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_])\w\S
```

So, for example, this string `www.somesite.com/user/username` should return true, while this one `www.somesite.com/user` - false.

For some reason it works only if I have at least 3 chars after the `somesite.com/user/` part. So `somesite.com/user/me` returns false. And `somesite.com/user/someuser` returns true only for `somesite.com/user/som`.

The only allowed chars after the `user/` part should be a-z, A_Z, 0-9, dash and underscore.

How can I make it work?

Comment: "if a certain string exists in another string and has any amount of chars after that" = "if a certain string exists in another string", isn't it? Or do you mean 1 or more chars?

Comment: Try [`somesite\.com\/user\/[\w-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lLF0v0/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, wrong click. Fixed it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three chars are required aftr `user/` because `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\w\S` match (and thus require) three chars to exist after `user/`.

You seem to need

```
somesite\.com\/user\/[\w-]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLF0v0/2)

Note that `.` should be escaped to match a literal dot. `\w` usually stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`  by default, so you may shorten the pattern a bit using this shorthand character class.

**Details**

- `somesite\.com\/user\/` - a `somesite.com/user/` substring
- `[\w-]+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits, `_`) and/or `-`

**JS demo**:

```js
var ss = ['www.somesite.com/user/username', 'somesite.com/user/me', 'www.somesite.com/user'];
var rx = /somesite\.com\/user\/[\w-]+/g;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.match(rx));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the detailed explanation! Worked just as needed! Will accept the answer once SO allows it in a few minutes!

Comment: For some reason it didn't work locally... I tried this `var pattern = new RegExp('somesite\.com\/user\/[\w-]+'); var res = pattern.test(myStr);` and I'm always getting false.

Comment: @Igal Ah, so it is JavaScript, let me add a demo. You cannot use single backslashes for regex escapes in constructor RegExp notation. Use a regex literal as your pattern is not dynamic: `var rx = /somesite\.com\/user\/[\w-]+/g;`

Comment: Awesome! Now it worked as it should. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try `(somesite.com\/user\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)`

You can validate your regex here:
https://regex101.com/